# How to located google map marker (lat and lng) by user entered(useForm hook) data

Tags: javascript

For example I filled Form data with my complete address , based on that address I want to located the same address in google maps (just Like we enter the address in Food delivery app map located us in exact location)

I try by giving lat and lng , but am expecting how we will find exact location in google maps through users data.